# Some questions about using NDK for faster programming results

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have the following questions, please if you know the answers share it with me.

- How can I transform my working Java code to NDK? (it's an algoritm not activity)
- I am able to access the database from NDK?
- Will a backtracking algorithm with 10 millions of iterations run faster if was written with NDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android NDK allows you to use native (c/c++) code in your Android application.  So, you would need to convert your code to c or c++.

The Android database is typically SQLite, so you would need a c/c++ interface for interacting with it.  The docs don't talk about giving you that..

From the docs:

> Typical good candidates for the NDK
>   are self-contained, CPU-intensive
>   operations that don't allocate much
>   memory, such as signal processing,
>   physics simulation, and so on. Simply
>   re-coding a method to run in C usually
>   does not result in a large performance
>   increase. The NDK can, however, can be
>   an effective way to reuse a large
>   corpus of existing C/C++ code.

If your algorithm is cpu intensive, doesn't allocate much memory, and could be optimized in c/c++ it might be worth a shot..